# ImportError: cannot import name 'mock_s3' from 'moto'

Tags: python, moto

```py
import pytest
from moto import mock_s3


@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def s3():
    with mock_s3():
        os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] = 'test'
        os.environ['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] = 'test'
        os.environ['AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'] = 'us-east-1'
        s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
        s3.create_bucket(Bucket='test_bucket')
        yield s3
```

This code was working, but is now throwing an exception `Cannot import name mock_s3 from moto`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Simply replace your import of `mock_s3` with `from moto import mock_aws` and use `with mock_aws():` instead.

Moto was recently bumped to version 5.0, and you were probably running 4.x before.

https://github.com/getmoto/moto/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

If you check the change log, you will see that an important breaking change was made:

> All decorators have been replaced with a single decorator: `mock_aws`

Comment: Lifesaver, thanks. I hadn't versioned `moto` in my requirements file, so it was installing the latest version, where `mock_s3` was deprecated.